# Error by trying installing docker repository on linux ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu

Sorry the language is german.

So I added the repository of the docker:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) stable"
```

But I get Errors when I update the sources:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

> Ign:3 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic InRelease
>
> Fehl:4 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic Release
>   Certificate verification failed: The certificate is NOT trusted. The
>   certificate issuer is unknown.  Could not handshake: Error in the
>   certificate verification. [IP: 54.230.93.95 443]
>
> Holen:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
>   [74,6 kB]
>
> OK:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
>
> Paketlisten werden gelesen... Fertig E: Das Depot
>   »https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic Release« enthält
>   keine Release-Datei.
>
> N: Eine Aktualisierung von solch einem Depot kann nicht auf eine
>   sichere Art durchgeführt werden, daher ist es standardmäßig
>   deaktiviert.
>
> N: Weitere Details zur Erzeugung von Paketdepots sowie zu deren
>   Benutzerkonfiguration finden Sie in der Handbuchseite apt-secure(8).

Comment: Have you read https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/ ? RTFD

Comment: yes sure. as you see the repository cannot refreshed and i Need the repository to download docker-ce , because without the repository it Shows me this:
after writing sudo apt-get install docker-ce i get a Messages says that docker-ce does not exist and try from anothe packet source

Comment: `Certificate verification failed` did you follow the steps in `Install using the repository` ?? `curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -` and `apt-key fingerprint 0EBFCD88` ?

Comment: yes i did that .first i get OK and when i check the Fingerprint :                apt-key fingerprint 0EBFCD88
pub   rsa4096 2017-02-22 [SCEA]
      9DC8 5822 9FC7 DD38 854A  E2D8 8D81 803C 0EBF CD88
uid           [ unknown] Docker Release (CE deb) <docker@docker.com>
sub   rsa4096 2017-02-22 [S]                it seems all good

Comment: more imformatiom    'curl -kv -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -'
   Trying 54.192.130.134...
 Connected to download.docker.com (54.192.130.134) port 443 (#0)
 ALPN, offering h2
successfully set certificate verify locations:
ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol** Server certificate:
**SSL certificate verify result: unable to get local issuer certificate (20), continuing anyway.**]
GET /linux/ubuntu/gpg HTTP/1.1  Host: download.docker.com
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
* Connection #0 to host download.docker.com left intact
OK

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/#install-using-the-repository

Comment: @Hozen well, install cacert , without it you will never get a working ssl. `apt-get install -y ca-certificates` + `sudo update-ca-certificates`.

Comment: apt-get install -y ca-certificates 
Statusinformationen werden eingelesen.... Fertig
ca-certificates ist schon die neueste Version (20180409).
0 aktualisiert, 0 neu installiert, 0 zu entfernen und 0 nicht aktualisiert.
update-ca-certificates
Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs...
0 added, 0 removed; done.
Running hooks in /etc/ca-certificates/update.d...
done.

Comment: i still have the Problem ,, i cant install docker-ce because the source not exist

Answer (score 22):

For those still having this issue, here is a solution which I gleaned from the [Ubuntu manpages](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/apt-transport-https.1.html).

The OP's post indicates a certificate verification error:

```
Certificate verification failed: The certificate is NOT trusted. The certificate issuer is unknown. Could not handshake: Error in the certificate verification. [IP: 54.230.93.95 443]
```

I was having similar issues on a VM which sits behind a corporate proxy.  The proxy acts as a man-in-the-middle, decrypting and re-encrypting traffic as it flows through the proxy.  Even though I had the trusted certificate installed on my VM for the proxy, this error was still happening, caused by an invalid OCSP response.  To fix it, I ran this command:

```
touch /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99verify-peer.conf \
&& echo >>/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99verify-peer.conf "Acquire { https::Verify-Peer false }"
```

This disables apt's OCSP verification, and is not recommended.

I chose a different solution, which may not be available to others.  Our company maintains a non-decrypting proxy for use cases like this, so I switched to using it.

Comment: Could you tell me, how to turn on certificate verification?

Comment: Since I don't know how it got turned off for you, I can only suggest that you try this command:

touch /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99verify-peer.conf \
&& echo >>/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99verify-peer.conf "Acquire { https::Verify-Peer true }"

Comment: worked like a charm. thanks @WPWoodJr

Comment: this is very extreme to assume that a proxy strips TLS header. I have a similar error and I tried `curl -v https://download.docker.com` and I see `SSL certificate verify ok.` this error can occur, and most likely occurs, for other reasons